# Sending Email using Javamail via Exchange

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I'm having some troubles sending emails via Javamail using my company exchange server. We have an application that was sending emails via the gmail server without any problems, but for some changes in the policies of Google we want to use the company server to do the job.
Im sure the problem in the session properties, but i cant find a way to make it work

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _server);

    session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
    try {
        transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("mail.company.com",_user,_pass);
        transport.close();
```

This is the error is showing the log

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.company.com, port: 443;
>   nested exception is:
>   avax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: 443 is HTTPS standard port. Seems your port 465 is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check your email provider and its SMTP settings; server, port and encryption method.

The following code snippet works with me

Put

```
        //1) get the session object     
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        // You have missed this line.
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        // This SMTP server works with me for all Microsoft email providers, like: -
        // Outlook, Hotmail, Live, MSN, Office 365 and Exchange.
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.pwd", password);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
        session.setDebug(true); // To trace the code implementation.

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.live.com", 587, user, password);
        transport.close();
```

instead of

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _server);

    session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
    try {
        transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("mail.company.com",_user,_pass);
        transport.close();
```

I found [this website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-and-imap-email-settings-for-outlook-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353) so helpful, in getting other email providers SMTP settings information.

Comment: I was using the incorrect port, after talking with my server administrator he said that the correct port is "25". Im now currently struggling with the authentication. Its like if the server dont read the user/pass data

Comment: You can use the code above to fix the issue, then check if it stills, you must make sure that you entered the correct user(**Your email address**) and password(**Your email password**); usually an exception will occur if it's not.
If it stills, you must make sure about your email SMTP server settings.
By the way what is your email provider? Microsoft Exchange? if you don't know, give me the login page link of your company emails and I'll look for its SMTP server settings then I will edit the answer.